# Check if a jar file runing in linux server or not

Tags: java, linux, jar

I need to run a jar file in my linux VPS server for the whole day(continuously). But it stops in some time while running. 
For this I need to check if there is a way to check if the .jar file is running or not using a cronjob. if the file not running the cronjob can start the .jar file again.
can anybody help me?
If this question already answered plz send link.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First check if the jar you are running already offers some kind of "watchdog" functionality. If yes, use this functionality unless is doesn't fit your needs. If it doesn't have such a functionality and you cannot change the source code, then you should look for the PID as mentioned in the answer from nablex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this bit to get the pid:

```
JBOSS_PID=`ps -ef | grep org.jboss.modules.Main | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
```

This is an example for a jboss server, you can see the main class in the grep. Switch this for your own class.

If the pid does not exist, start it. Run as frequently as you want.

Comment: my module is buz_messenger. How can i use for this.
Sorry I'm not expert in java programing

Comment: How do you start it? With a bash file? If so, you can find the name of the main class in the bash file.

Comment: Im using 
java -cp buz_messenger.jar com.svs.trade.server.buz_messenger

Comment: Then the class is `com.svs.trade.server.buz_messenger` (odd name for a class but hey...). Replace the `org.jboss.modules.Main` with that class